# Copying files makes Handbrake faster on a mac?

Tags: macos, mac, handbrake

I'm seeing something extremely odd.

Handbrake on my mac is being throttled to ≈60% CPU usage.  I've been trying to figure out why for a while with no luck.

Now for the odd part --

When I'm actively copying files to an external drive, Handbrake is suddenly allowed to use 80-90% of my CPU.

Yes, I know that sounds insane.  Here are some screenshots:

[Not copying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw65T.png)
[Copying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdFNe.png)

According to Activity monitor, each Handbrake instance is using ≈450% (16 core machine) when I'm not doing anything and ≈700% when I'm copying files.

I'm really just wondering what on Earth is going on here.  If anyone has any advice on how to get Handbrake to stop being throttled, that'd also be great :)

Comment: Idea: If the 60% CPU usage limit is because of some limit of Handbrake, then copying files might slow down the computer enough to convince Handbrake to add more cores in order to catch up.